# Creating a 2d matrix in python

Tags: python, list

I create a 6x5 2d array, initially with just None in each cell. I then read a file and replace the Nones with data as I read them. I create the empty array first because the data is in an undefined order in the file I'm reading.  My first attempt I did this:

```
x = [[None]*5]*6
```

which resulted in some weird errors that I now understand is because the * operator on lists may create references instead of copies.

Is there an easy one liner to create this empty array? I could just do some for loops and build it up, but that seems needlessly verbose for python.

Comment: If you're dealing with n-dimensional arrays, you should at least be aware that numpy exists: http://numpy.scipy.org/  There's nothing wrong with nested lists, of course, and adding a (large) dependency like numpy is not always a good thing.  However, if you don't already know about it, well, now you do!

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Using nested comprehension lists :

```
x = [[None for _ in range(5)] for _ in range(6)]
```

Answer (score 32):

What's going on here is that the line

```
x = [[None]*5]*6
```

expands out to

```
x = [[None, None, None, None, None, None]]*6
```

At this point you have a list with 6 different references to the singleton `None`. You also have a list with a reference to the inner list as it's first and only entry. When you multiply it by 6, you are getting 5 more references to the inner list as you understand. But the point is that theres no problem with the *inner list*, just the outer one so there's no need to expand the construction of the inner lists out into a comprehension.

```
x = [[None]*5 for _ in range(6)]
```

This avoids duplicating references to any lists and is about as concise as it  can readably get I believe.

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't going the numpy route, you can fake 2D arrays with dictionaries:

```
>>> x = dict( ((i,j),None) for i in range(5) for j in range(6) )
>>> print x[3,4]
None
```